# Selecting Multiple dates in Dojo Calendar widget

Tags: javascript, json, dojo

I'm currently using the dojo calendar widget like in 
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/widget/Calendar.html

My requirement is this:

1. Select multiple dates to mark the selected dates as holiday and save it in DB.
2. Push the selected dates as JSON or array
3. Upon selecting a date, the background color needs to marked in some color to confirm it is selected.
4. Upon deselecting, the background color needs to be changed back to white to confirm its unselected.

How could this be accomplished?
Help appreciated much..

-Vinoth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this :

```
 <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var selectedDates = {};
    </script>
 </head>
 <body class="soria">
    <style type="text/css">
        @import "dojox/widget/Calendar/Calendar.css";
    </style>
    <div dojoType="dojox.widget.Calendar">
        <script type="dojo/connect" event="onValueSelected" args="date">
            if (!selectedDates[date]) {
                selectedDates[date] = 1;
            } else {
                delete selectedDates[date];
            }
            var list = dojo.byId("selectedDates");
            dojo.attr(list, "innerHTML", "");
            for (var date in selectedDates) {
                if (selectedDates.hasOwnProperty(date)) {
                    dojo.create("li", {"innerHTML":date}, list);
                }
            }

        </script>
    </div>
    <ul id="selectedDates"></ul>
</body>
```

I didn't figure out how to keep the selected cells coloured yet, but it should be doable...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. Worked perfect but i couldn't make the color change for selection and unselection :(

Answer (score 3):

There's an experimental [MultiSelectCalendar](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.7.0/dojo-release-1.7.0/dojox/widget/tests/test_MultiSelectCalendar.html) widget

Comment: thanks for pointing out MultiSelectCalendar widget. But thats available in dojo 1.7 and i use dojo 1.6 :(
My client wont approve 1.7 in near future. Is there a way to highlight the selected date in some color?

Comment: Hey that looks great ! @Vinoth : maybie you can have a look at this new widget code and reimplement the colouring part on your 1.6 version ?! I haven't looked at it yet though so I have no idea how difficult this can be...

Comment: @Vinoth, you can try looking at some of the older patches from the enhancement ticket http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/9679 where I think it was originally designed against Dojo 1.6.

Comment: Hmm I could try that. Btw can I take the multiSelectCalendar.js alone from 1.7 trunk and merge it with 1.6? Will that work or have to do anything extra to make it work? As per my understanding, something has to be done in dojo.js I guess.

Comment: IIRC, MultiSelectCalendar uses private APIs and is not compatible across 1.6/1.7 releases where there was a major refactor of Calendar.